# Hide System Tray Icon of a 3rd party exe

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to hide the system tray icon of a program that I'm calling with my program. I'm currently working on a program that provides guides and quick resources to other members of my team. I've got the program to load an AutoHotKey file at launch but the AHK icon shows in the System Tray/Notification area of the task bar. I would like to hide that icon.

I'm currently working in VB.net

So, I don't want to hide anything from the taskbar, I just want to hide the icon of AHK from the system tray.

I have done some looking around and seen some things with the Shell_NotifyIcon but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. AutoHotKey has a built in feature to hide the tray icon.

## HideTrayIcon

Place that inside the script and it will not show it in the system tray.